# React ref gives undefine in custom input of material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working in react where i have provide custom input.Custom Input are use in some component by providing myRef as props for ref of react. However all process are fine but it show value undefined in console.

**Custom Input**

```
class CustomInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
      const { classes, formControlProps, labelText, id, labelProps,inputRef, inputProps, error, success } = this.props;
    return (
        <FormControl {...formControlProps} className={formControlProps.className + " " + classes.formControl}>
            {labelText !== undefined ? (<InputLabel
                classes={{
                    root: classes.labelRoot + (error ? " " + classes.labelRootError:success ? " " + classes.labelRootSuccess:""),
                }}
                htmlFor={id}
                {...labelProps}
            >
                {labelText}
            </InputLabel>):null}
            <Input
                classes={{
                    root: (labelText !== undefined ? "":classes.marginTop),
                    disabled: classes.disabled,
                    underline: classes.underline,
                    inkbar: (error ? classes.inkbarError:success ? classes.inkbarSuccess:classes.inkbar),
                }}
                id={id}
                ref={inputRef} //Here ref props is map with inputRef
                {...inputProps}
            />
            {error ? <Clear className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootError}/>:success ? <Check className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootSuccess}/>:null}
        </FormControl>
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage of custom input in Other Component**

```
handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.email.value); //show undefined in console
        }
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <CustomInput
            labelText="Email"
            id="email"
            inputRef={(input) => {this.email = input}} // provided inputRef Prop
            formControlProps={{
                fullWidth: true
            }}
            inputProps ={{
                type:"email",
            }}
        />
        </ItemGrid>
     </form>
```

Comment: Have u bind the `handleSubmit` function in the constructor

Comment: no i have bind in constructor, but why we need to bind in constructor

Comment: Its okay you have binded in the form tag.What does `this.email` gives in console.log`

Comment: this.email.value provide undefined in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your code in a CodeSandbox editor and it seems to work fine.
When I press enter (submit the form) I get the email logged in the console. That if the email is valid.

Could you look and maybe explain to us better what is the problem? Maybe I did not understand exactly what you were saying.

LE: `ref` works on native `input` element. For the custom `Input` from `react-ui-next` you should use `inputRef`.

[image: Edit kx11z14w5o]

Comment: I am using material-ui with react. Where Input and FormControl are component of material-ui.

Comment: I have updated the CodeSandbox with a working example using `react-ui-next`.

You should use `inputRef` instead of `ref` on the `Input` component that comes from `react-ui-next`.